# Spec says 7-24V, can I use 25V?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I'm building an IoT device with a Wemos D1 Mini. It should control a relay, and also measure the temperature. The thing is, my only practical power source comes from my garage door opener which I measured to be 25.1V. What would happen if I then use [this powershield](https://wiki.wemos.cc/products:d1_mini_shields:dc_power_shield) rated for 7-24V? If it won't work, what are my options? Maybe I could make my own shield with higher input range, but that seems to be a lot of work.. What are my options?

Comment: You can use whatever you want. If you want a piece of equipment to work (including not blowing up)  as per the datasheet then complying to it is usually a good idea

Comment: Simply use a different power supply that gives you 3.3V. If the datasheet says "nope", and alternatives are plenty, why even bother trying to use this specific device?

Comment: Have you read this? "1) Exceeding these ratings may damage the device. "

Comment: The simplest would appear to be to create a lower supply rail with an  adjustable linear regulator if the power  loss wont be too high or add a simple buck regulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better than diodes, use a dc-dc buck converter.  For 2-3 dollars (from china) you can get one with up to 36V input and 3 to 5 amps output.

Comment: In other words, a version of what the proposed board is, but instead actually suited to the input voltage at hand.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of 3$ chinaware supplies, but this answer hits the nail on its proverbial head: instead of using something unsuitable, use something in the same price range that's suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Put some diodes in series with the power source. Like 4 or 5 you're probably safe in case the power source exceeds 25.1V. Make sure to pick the right current rating.
(The current rating is determined by the power shield).

Comment: Seconded - this is the simplest solution. However, make sure that your 25V source really cannot rise to something higher. A 25V output seems a bit odd, which means it is probably not regulated.

Comment: A better solution is to use a single high current rated zener or tvs that opens at ~24V, to burn away the excess.

Comment: @Lundin Provided you (roughly) know the current limit of the power source, otherwise it might burn away itself instead of the excess.

Comment: Huh? What does that have to do anything? Obviously I am _not_ suggesting to put the zener in series with the supply! But between supply and ground. The only thing that matters is the reverse current over the zener. Picking one rated at 1A or so is pretty much standard.

Comment: Exactly. If the power source becomes 24.5V and can deliver 10A and the zener clamps to 24V the reverse current through the zener will be almost 10A, and it will burn away the zener.

Answer (score 1):

This board uses the chip MP2359.

This chip is rated for 4.5V to 24V, however, if you check the chip Maximum rating, it is rated 26V.

The input Capacitor is rated 25V.

Usually, the manufacturer always keep a good 10% safety margin on top of those ratings, so you have good chances that it would just work fine.

Given the price it's not a huge risk anyway.

EDIT:

Following some comments. Justme pointed out that there is a diode at the input which would have a voltage drop of at least 0.3V bringing the input at 24.8VDC.

The 25.1V power supply is also likely to be a 24VDC supply that is under no load given 25.1 is not really a standard supply.

Comment: I personally don't like to get 20~30% close to capacitors in generals voltage ratings. More if its tantalum. And for MLCCs also depending on how critical the total capacitance is.

Comment: In this board it's a ceramic cap, that would be 0.1V beyond the rating (0.4%).

Comment: That is a problem itself - mulitlater ceramic caps do not have their nominal value at high voltages even *within* their rating limit.  This is *not* a good idea, and is poor advice.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Interesting, would it have a big difference between 24 and 25V ?

Comment: That powershield also has a diode on input, so voltage at input cap and buck regulator will be somewhat less than what is at input connector, but I would not count on it. Perhaps adding few more diodes drops voltage enough? A resistor might work too to drop voltage.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the schematic you'll find that the regulator is MP2359. Reading the datasheet, it doesn't really specify the supply voltage other than in the summary where it says 24V. Absolute maximum ratings is 26V but you shouldn't design based on that.

Furthermore, there is a schottky SS24 in series with the supply. It has a forward voltage of < 0.5V depending on current drawn. It still leaves you a tiny bit outside the spec.

If you want to be dead certain that everything works you could add a 24V zener or TVS on the input line and let it burn away the extra voltage. Putting a TVS there might not be a bad idea for other reasons, depending on how trusty your supply is. It doesn't sound like it is of particularly high quality.

Answer (score -2):

You measure 25.1v on your power supply today. What might it be tomorrow, at a different temperature, or when unloaded, or when the load kicks back?

Going above max recommended voltage is never a good idea. It might stay working, it might not. It *will* probably run hotter than intended, shortening its working life.

The best thing to do would be to drop your supply voltage a bit. The 78xx series would be excellent for this. They are rated for 40v max input. Use a 7815 or a 7812 to drop the voltage to 15v or 12v respectively.

Comment: That powershield is rated for 1 A and your 7815/7812 can do 1 A or 1.5 A (depending on the manf.). You're recommending regulators that could drop 10..13 W at full load or s/c, or over a watt at just 100 mA load. We don't know what else the OP might load it with in the future. Downvoting, I'm afraid.

Comment: The linear regulator over such a drop is not a great idea, but this is so far the only answer to state the key point that the proposed supply *is not suitable*.

Comment: We also don't know what the 25.1V supply is presently providing.  Adding 25W may cause the 25.1V supply to fail.